# How to keep access to server after OpenVPN client connection is established?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I want to connect to OpenVPN from my server (Ubuntu command line server, but connect as client), but the problem is that if I connect, the client (my server), will be inaccessible, and I cannot SSH to that.

How can I do this but still maintain access? I mean, the client's outgoing traffic should only go from `tun` device for example.